# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have tried many.
First, I changed these.

- And Change php.ini and my.ini
- post_max_size = 750M
- upload_max_filesize = 750M
- max_execution_time =    5000
- max_input_time = 5000
- memory_limit = 1000M
- max_allowed_packet =          200M (in my.ini)

and add this

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;
```

to phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Second,

In the my.ini file, edit the “max_allowed_packet” by increasing the value.
XAMPP default value is 1M. I updated it to 10M.

But I could't solve it.
The following is the error contents.

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in         
C:\xampp\htdocs\escape_room\Login.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. 
PID=5632 in C:\xampp\htdocs\escape_room\Login.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\escape_room\Login.php on line 8

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\escape_room\Login.php on line 8
```

https: // ip_number / escape_room / accessed, but if I try to access Login.php, I get an error.
I'm testing when I approach from the outside.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly possible that you changed the values in the wrong file.

First of all I would check the actual configuration. You can do that easily in XAMPP by looking at this page:
http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php

Then search for max_execution time. You'll find a line like this:

[image]

If that doesn't have your updated max_execution_time you changed the wrong file.
You would need to change this file ...\xampp\php\php.ini

Do the same with all the other variables you mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you. I've checked everything, and I've made changes that have not been fixed. However, MySQL server has gone away, Error while reading greeting packet PID = 7728 in ... still occurs.

Comment: The MySQL issue is probably caused by something completely different. I would open a new question just with this issue and give a lot more detail to it if possible. Have you taken a look at this? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Thank you. I'll try mysql_ping ().